# Why wont this query work?

Tags: mysql

#1305 - FUNCTION n.DATE_FORMAT does not exist

SELECT
    n.title,
    g.title,
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(n.data), '%d') day
FROM  news as n 
INNER JOIN(
     SELECT COUNT(id_news) _COUNT ,DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(data), '%d') _day FROM news GROUP BY _day) as n2

ON n2._day= n.DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(n.data), '%d')

INNER JOIN `group` AS g ON g.`group_id`=n.`id_group`
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(n.data), '%d')

Comment: A little formatting and some background info never hurt.

Comment: Table news does not contain field day?

Answer (score 1):

1.You cannot use **ALIAS** of column in `ON Clause`

```
SELECT
    n.title,
    g.title,
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(n.data), '%d') day
FROM  news as n 
INNER JOIN(
     SELECT COUNT(id_news) _COUNT ,DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(data), '%d') _day FROM news GROUP BY _day) as n2  
ON n2._day= n.DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(n.data), '%d')
INNER JOIN `group` AS g ON g.`group_id`=n.`id_group`
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(n.data), '%d')
```